# How can I remove the last two values in each key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to remove the last values of each key of a dictionary. For example:

```
mydic = {'a': [2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,6,7], 'c': [9,10,3,4,5,6]}
```

I want to create a new sub-dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {'a': [2,3] 'b':[5] 'c': [9,10,3,4]}
```

How can I obtain the second dictionary from the first?

Comment: You should add a tag at least to the question stating which language you're asking about.  I'm assuming JavaScript from the syntax, but could be others.

Comment: Thank you so much. I  forgot that. I am using Python

Comment: As originally posted, this is not valid Python syntax.  Please double check things before posting your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specified which values you like to remove, but the expected result shows that you removed 2 last.

```
>>> mydic = {'a':[2,3,4,5], 'b':[5,6,7], 'c':[9,10,3,4,5,6]}
>>> new_dic = {key: mydic[: -2] for key in mydic}
>>> new_dict
{'a': [2, 3, 4], 'c': [9, 10, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [5, 6]}
```

But, if your list (values) don't have items enough, you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
newdict = {key: mydic[:-2] for key in mydic}
```